# Update QuantLib in Python

Tags: python, updates, quantlib

Updating existing Quantlib package with new updates in Python.

I need to update already available and functioning QuantLib package in Python. New release is available which I need to use. Tried looking various sites (including stackoverflow) but could not get right process. Most are explaining Quantlib install, not specific to updates.

Comment: I think really what you want is "how to upgrade some python package."  In your case, it is probably `pip install QuantLib-Python --upgrade`

Comment: i used that too but cannot see new QuantLib library/functions